# Best way to store very large weighted DAG on disk?

Tags: bigdata, graph-databases, directed-acyclic-graphs, memory-efficient, connected-components

Assume a graph database to store a very large DAG on disk:

There are many things that are **not** required, which allows for optimization.

Basically what I do need is:

- store a directed acyclic graph, no cycles, at most one edge per node-pair
- `fromID`, `toID`, `weight` (can be `INT`,`INT`,`FLOAT`)
- return *connected components* efficiently and conveniently
- return all *zero-indegeree nodes* efficiently and conveniently
- return all *descendents* of a node efficiently and conveniently
- manage sizes of up to *100 million nodes*, with up to *10 billion edges*
- modest resource requirements
- free / open-source

Do you have some experience that allow you to give recommendations?

Comment: What do you mean by "modest resource requirements"? Objectivity/DB is regularly used to store billions and/or trillions of nodes and edges on architectures that are single-server, distributed multi-server, and cloud/cluster configurations. Graphs can span multiple servers.

Comment: Certainly one Server. Obviously, it cannot work magic if I want so many nodes and quick responses, but if it could drop all unnecessary aspects and then is still low on RAM and disk use... Say at most 64GB RAM and 1TB Disk...

Comment: I had similar idea, I end up using an OKVS.